# Scraping data using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the names of each of the search results from this page using the code below:

```
url2 <- "http://www.truckandtrailer.ca/search.cfm?intIndustryID=2&searchtype=advanced&pageaction=showresults&bitNew=0&intCategoryID=30&intMakeID=0&intSelectProvinceID=&x=26&y=6"

results <- url2 %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(".desc_title") %>%
  html_text()
results
```

However it just returns:

```
character(0)
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution using RSelenium and rvest.

Note: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780170/web-scrapping-the-make-model-year-of-vin-numbers-in-rstudio) for working with RSelenium and rvest.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
startServer() 
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'firefox')
remDr$open()

url2 <- "http://www.truckandtrailer.ca/search.cfm?intIndustryID=2&searchtype=advanced&pageaction=showresults&bitNew=0&intCategoryID=30&intMakeID=0&intSelectProvinceID=&x=26&y=6"
remDr$navigate(url2)
test.html <- html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
  results<-test.html %>%
  html_nodes(".desc_title") %>%
  html_text(trim=TRUE)
  results

[1] "2009 FREIGHTLINER FLD 132 CLASSIC XL HIGHWAY TR..." "2014 FREIGHTLINER CASCADIA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"        
 [3] "2014 KENWORTH W900-L HIGHWAY TRACTOR"               "2014 KENWORTH T660 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
 [5] "2013 FREIGHTLINER CASCADA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"          "2013 FREIGHTLINER CASCADA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"         
 [7] "(5) 2013 FREIGHTLINER CASCADIA - 113 HIGHWAY TR..." "(2) 2013 INTERNATIONAL PROSTAR HIGHWAY TRACTOR"    
 [9] "2013 KENWORTH T660 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "2013 KENWORTH W900B HIGHWAY TRACTOR"               
[11] "(2) 2013 KENWORTH T700 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"             "2013 KENWORTH W900 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[13] "2013 KENWORTH T660 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "2013 KENWORTH W900L HIGHWAY TRACTOR"               
[15] "2013 KENWORTH W900L HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                "2013 KENWORTH W900 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[17] "2013 PETERBILT 388 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "(5) 2013 PETERBILT 388 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"            
[19] "2013 PETERBILT 389 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "2013 PETERBILT 388 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[21] "2013 VOLVO VNL670 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                  "2013 VOLVO VNL630 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 
[23] "(5) 2012 FREIGHTLINER CASCADIA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"     "2012 FREIGHTLINER CA125 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"           
[25] "(2) 2012 FREIGHTLINER CASCADIA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"   
remDr$close()
```

Another approach is to use Phantomjs (no need to use cmd and no extra browser). The only thing that you need here is to download the exe file from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and place this in your R working directory (you can also specify the path if you don't want to place this in your working directory).

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
pJS <- phantom(extras = c('--ssl-protocol=tlsv1'))
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantom")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.truckandtrailer.ca/search.cfm?intIndustryID=2&searchtype=advanced&pageaction=showresults&bitNew=0&intCategoryID=30&intMakeID=0&intSelectProvinceID=&x=26&y=6")
test.html <- html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
results<-test.html %>%
       html_nodes(".desc_title") %>%
      html_text(trim=TRUE)
> results
[1] "2009 FREIGHTLINER FLD 132 CLASSIC XL HIGHWAY TR..." "2014 FREIGHTLINER CASCADIA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"        
[3] "2014 KENWORTH W900-L HIGHWAY TRACTOR"               "2014 KENWORTH T660 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[5] "2013 FREIGHTLINER CASCADA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"          "2013 FREIGHTLINER CASCADA HIGHWAY TRACTOR"         
[7] "(5) 2013 FREIGHTLINER CASCADIA - 113 HIGHWAY TR..." "(2) 2013 INTERNATIONAL PROSTAR HIGHWAY TRACTOR"    
[9] "2013 KENWORTH T660 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "2013 KENWORTH W900B HIGHWAY TRACTOR"               
[11] "(2) 2013 KENWORTH T700 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"             "2013 KENWORTH W900 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[13] "2013 KENWORTH T660 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "2013 KENWORTH W900L HIGHWAY TRACTOR"               
[15] "2013 KENWORTH W900L HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                "2013 KENWORTH W900 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[17] "2013 PETERBILT 388 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "(5) 2013 PETERBILT 388 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"            
[19] "2013 PETERBILT 389 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                 "2013 PETERBILT 388 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                
[21] "2013 VOLVO VNL670 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"                  "2013 VOLVO VNL630 HIGHWAY TRACTOR"    
remDr$close
pJS$stop()
```

P.S. Please see the [help](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html) file for details.